# uninitialized constant WhatCountsNewsletter::WhatCounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I am getting an error while sending the email so please have look

```
NameError in Siteman/newslettersController#send_to_testers

uninitialized constant WhatCountsNewsletter::WhatCounts

RAILS_ROOT: /var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:131:in `rescue in const_missing'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:120:in `const_missing'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/app/models/what_counts_newsletter.rb:22:in `configure_whatcounts_client'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/app/models/what_counts_newsletter.rb:66:in `deliver_as_test'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/app/controllers/siteman/newsletters_controller.rb:101:in `send_to_testers'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/app/controllers/siteman/siteman_controller.rb:31:in `call'
/var/www/sites/preit/releases/siteman/app/controllers/siteman/siteman_controller.rb:31:in `block in <class:SitemanController>'
```

newsletters_controller.rb

```
 def send_to_testers
@newsletter = @current_website.newsletters.find(params[:id])
@newsletter.update_attributes(params[:newsletter])

audit_trail "Newsletter \##{@newsletter.id}: #{@newsletter.list_id} #{@newsletter.name}  was delivered to the Test Recipients."
# Error Checking & Reporting!
results = @newsletter.deliver_as_test(@current_user)
logger.debug "[DBUG] Test Send Results: #{results}"
render :text => "Test E-Mails Delivered, now you can sent email to subscribers OR further tests can be sent instead", :status => 200
```

end

what_counts_newsletter.rb

```
 def configure_whatcounts_client
newsletter = self
WhatCounts::HttpClient.configure do
  realm    newsletter.realm
  password newsletter.password
end
```

end

```
def deliver_as_test(initiated_by)
configure_whatcounts_client
WhatCounts::OneOffMessage.send!(:list_id     => list_id,
                                :subject     => "[TEST] #{subject_line}",
                                :to          => approval_recipients,
                                :format      => 2)
remove_lock
update_attribute(:last_tested_at, Time.zone.now)
```

end

Comment: Looks to me like class `WhatCounts::HttpClient` cannot be found. There could be several reasons for it: a missing require statement, a misnamed file or directory (if you use Rails autoloading), a typo in either the module or class name...